# What is the optimum swap size on Linux for a heavily threaded program?

Tags: linux, memory, amazon-ec2

I using an Amazon EC2 server small instance and by default it allows 382 threads per process. However, I wish to run 10,000 threads in a single process. Recently, I learned that this can be done by either reducing the stack limit or increasing virtual memory.

To the best of my knowledge, virtual memory can be increased by increasing RAM or swap space in Linux. Increasing RAM is not an option. I know how to increase swap space, but I am not sure what the optimum size I should go for is.

What I am not clear on is, how do swap space and RAM work when I run threads? Is there some specific limit after which swap memory makes the threads slow? Is there an optimal amount of swap space I should use?:

Comment: What are you running that needs 10k threads?  Can you find a solution that won't need that much?

Comment: I am scaling a crawler to crawl 2M urls in one day. I can try to find a different approach that won't need that much threads but first I wish to understand disadvantages of using 10,000 threads. My prime focus is to utilize the server resources fully.

Comment: Looks like *huge* amounts of swap will help there. Those threads will be swapped out most of their lifetime, waiting for input.

Comment: 10,000 threads isn't a good way to make things scale, it is a good way to make a server come to a crawl, more than 1 thread per CPU or Core is just going to make the server context switch and run slower not faster.

Comment: @ZJR If your concurrency is greater then number of available cores this fact won't help you because swapping context in and out from Disk is quite likely to bleed into wake up time for waiting threads.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Does it means threading too much is not the way to increase speed? I am using 32bit machine with single core so I guess the optimum number of threads should be somewhat which can keep cpu busy all the time but not overload or under-load it. Correct me if I am wrong. If I am correct, I wish to find out this value since my threads are totally cpu dependent, they might be sleeping for some server reponse, so I want to make sure CPU enough threads to work on at that time :)

Comment: @dragosrsupercool Make your threads not wait for server response. Send a request and move on to the next piece of data.  In this case I would say your 1 to 4 threads (I wouldn't start with more then that) will keep CPU busy for the rest of its life.  If you see that CPU is underloaded increase the number by 2 if overloaded cut it in half.

Comment: @Karlson: I am dedicating a thread for each url. What I was really planning was to find the average cpu time, wait time etc and on these factors decide total number of threads to run. Is this approach not ok? And i dont if this possible like one thread sending request to a server while other thread receiving the response. But yes if this can happen I wont need more than 3-4 threads

Comment: @dragosrsupercool I wouldn't do it this way.  The responses you get are for the most part if not completely are self contained so keeping data within a single thread that sends a request and then waits for response is to me useless.  I would use a thread pool to process data so when response arrive I just assign data to a thread and move on.

Comment: @Karlson : Can you explain your approach implementation using libcurl? Not waiting for response sounds good, but idk when a thread has sent a url how can the other thread receive the response?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2456/discussion-between-dragosrsupercool-and-karlson)

Comment: @dragosrsupercool Can't right now.

Answer (score 3):

Under Normal circumstances System Administrators make SWAP either 1x or 2x memory.  In your case I don't know if this will apply or even suffice.

Without having details of what you are running it is very difficult to know what would be the appropriate site of SWAP but in general whatever you run if it is swapped out to disk you will get performance degradation that can increase the time to run by orders of magnitude.  So before you go putting 10k threads that will be swapping like crazy may be you should look at the configuration or design of your application and do something else.

So analyze your application and determine the number of active concurrent threads and may be you don't need to run this many.

**SOLUTION APPROACH AS REQUESTED**

When you establish a connection to a website or webserver you maintain a list of requests sent to that particular connection, since responses will be received in order.  After a thread sends a request down to a server you wait in `select()` loop for data to become available.  When that happens you receive the data and send the request info and the received data down to another thread for processing.

Comment: I got it. 10x!!

Comment: the *use 1x or 2x ram for swap* number is way old. This should not be used anymore with modern computers. In some cases yes, but most machines you dont want gigabytes upon gigabytes of swap unless you need to hibernate.

Comment: @Patrick You're right but unless someone goes through the trouble of analyzing exactly how much will be used, and out of hundreds of systems I deployed I remember this done once, carving 64GB of swap out of 1+TB of diskspace is an easy and simple thing to do.